# Remove rows in a data.frame appearing in another data.frame by rowname() as id

Tags: r

I know there are some similar questions. But the answer for them doesn't help in my case or I did understand them wrong.

My example code

```
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(A = seq(20),
                 B1 = sample(c(T, F), 20, replace=T),
                 B2 = sample(c(T, F), 20, replace=T))

rownames(df) <- df$A
df <- df[, c('B1', 'B2'), drop = FALSE]

result <- df[df$B1 == FALSE & df$B2 == FALSE, ]

print(result)
```

Results in this

```
> result
      B1    B2
1  FALSE FALSE
4  FALSE FALSE
10 FALSE FALSE
16 FALSE FALSE
18 FALSE FALSE
```

So you see 5 cases at the end. I want this 5 cases be removed from the original data.frame `df` **without** loosing the `rownames()` or name the rows. So the rows with names `1, 4, 10, 16, 18` should be removed without causing renameing of the others rows.

What I tried (based on other answers):

```
> library(dplyr)
> anti_join(df, result)
Joining, by = c("B1", "B2")
      B1    B2
1   TRUE FALSE
2   TRUE  TRUE
3  FALSE  TRUE
4   TRUE  TRUE
5  FALSE  TRUE
6  FALSE  TRUE
7  FALSE  TRUE
8   TRUE  TRUE
9   TRUE  TRUE
10  TRUE FALSE
11 FALSE  TRUE
12  TRUE  TRUE
13  TRUE FALSE
14 FALSE  TRUE
15  TRUE FALSE
```

The rownames are not correct here. They are simply from 1 to 15.

Another try make no sense to me

```
> setdiff(df, result)
     B1    B2
1  TRUE FALSE
2  TRUE  TRUE
3 FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option with `setdiff` would be :

```
df[setdiff(rownames(df), rownames(result)), ]

#      B1    B2
#2   TRUE FALSE
#3   TRUE  TRUE
#5  FALSE  TRUE
#6   TRUE  TRUE
#7  FALSE  TRUE
#8  FALSE  TRUE
#9  FALSE  TRUE
#11  TRUE  TRUE
#12  TRUE  TRUE
#13  TRUE FALSE
#14 FALSE  TRUE
#15  TRUE  TRUE
#17  TRUE FALSE
#19 FALSE  TRUE
#20  TRUE FALSE
```

---

However, a more general approach I would suggest would be to calculate indices only once and use them.

```
inds <- df$B1 == FALSE & df$B2 == FALSE
result <- df[inds, ]
output <- df[!inds, ]
```

Comment: All your approaches working fine for my example but not for my real data. ;) `nrow(result)` is as expected **but** `nrow(output)` is not different from `nrow(df)`.

Comment: @buhtz I'll not be able to reproduce it since this works on example data. Can you update your example data which is similar to your actual data so that I could see where exactly it fails ?

Comment: R rownames are character. They should not be removed by numeric indexing. Use negation of `%in%` or `setdiff` for a general solution. There may also be the need to use as.character on the value from the other dataframe column if the chosen method does no automatically convert from factor to character.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `%in%` with `!`

```
df[!rownames(df) %in% rownames(result),]
```

Comment: Correct but not very useful in the explication of the specific issues faced by OP's question.